Would a pure iron core inductor be better for dampening capacitor bank startup current surge?
I was thinking and searching for how can a power converter handle power surges higher than its own sources limit. Particularly in two examples: buck converter that gives high current occasionally and similar inverter.
For buck converter, you want capacitors before reducing voltage, because the actual energy stored scales quadratically with the voltage.
For inverter, you just plain cannot store power in capacitors on the output.
In both these cases, I am assuming putting some capacitors before the power converter like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
But it immediately occurred to me that this would do the exact thing I don't want - draw much more from the source than is desired right after you connect it. Also, with larger voltages, this would probably make sparks in the main switch, which is not good.
But since inductor resists current until it is saturated, I thought this would be easy, lazy solution to somewhat mitigate the problem.
Now I am making these assumptions:

The inductor helps because it dampens the current surge until it is saturated
Iron is bad for transformers and switch mode supplies because of eddy currents, but in this case after the initial spike, the current should be constant most of the time
Iron has much higher magnetic permeability and therefore higher inductance can be accomplished with less turns of a wire allowing low resistance inductor

Is any of this correct? Is putting the inductor there helping anything in general, and an iron one in particular?
Note: I am aware that ideal solution here is to place a true constant current source between input and power converter (with a voltage limit), but that's way more complicated and would only make sense if the input was highly sensitive, which most sources are not.

The numbers are mostly random for now. I only put in 10mF to indicate that this is a larger bank. Once I have a real plan, I would calculate both the inductor (if it is useful at all) and the max capacitance that is safe without making the circuit more complex. The question here is just whether this mitigation is meaningful at all.

This is why power inverters have soft start capabilities. It's way easier to deal with the surge with a little bit of software vs trying to deal with it using a pre-filter.

@Burglups the same thing most power supplies do: 1MOhm or something shorted accross them discharges them. I thought about sequencing, because that's precisely what I did as a kid when playing with bunch of capacitors and ATX supply - just manually. But it is still way more complicated.

@Jon Yes, but soft start is only good if the limit it imposes does not affect function of the load. The idea I presented here is not a filter, that would be part of the converter or inverter. The goal of this extra charge is to allow power spikes on the load without hurting the source too much.

Have you tried to calculate or simulate it? Have you looked into other solutions?

Thanks for the articles, I am learning a lot. I can see that one of them mentions a simple inductor+capacitor solution. Neither seem to answer the question whether ordinary iron core would perform better when the input current is relatively stable, which is what my question is about.

@TomášZato ah, okay I see what you're asking. This method could work but it really depends on the specific values of storage capacitance you need and the in rush limit, plus the converter's characteristics. The circuit is a big L/C oscillator network - if it isn't damped properly it will cause lots of issues. We really need more information to know if this is suitable. As for an iron core - air cored inductors have very low inductance, so you'd almost certainly need a core or else the inductor would be huge. Yes it could be solid, but probably more expensive to make in volume anyway.

@Burglups Can you advise maybe how can I reword the question? My question is whether/how the core material the initial start-up - once the current is stable, it does not matter because it is saturated like I assumed in my question. Basically the question was whether it is true that iron core will have (in general) somewhat larger inductance compared to ferrite ignoring any high-frequency scenarios. The number of comments suggests it is not clear what I ask, as all the advice is focused on power supplies and not the inductor itself, while I used the power supply scenario for context.

That's the thing, I don't know how to do the math yet and don't have the tools to experiment. The best way I thought of is to go back to ATX and capacitor bank, keep adding until it kicks the fuse and then try making some inductors and see if they prevent the fuse from triggering. But I don't really have similar sized piece of iron and ferrite.

@TomášZato This EESE answer discusses using a series inductor, which I recall in some old power supplies. This EESE answer, towards the end, discusses the use of a relay that bypasses a series resistor on the primary of a transformer to limit inrush. This is an example of part of the HV power supply circuit for the Heathkit SB-1000. The first half-cycle is limited to about half the operating current pulse heights through the diodes. Old, passive ways.

@TomášZato Unfortunately, I haven't read through all this discussion except to notice suggestions requiring soft-start ICs and from there motion towards heavy iron. So all I am doing is throwing mud at the wall to see what sticks.
